# netbeans php - cannot get breakpoints to work

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, breakpoints

I have read and tried what I've found yet I cannot get it to work, it just keeps on hanging at "Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)" when starting debugging.

I do have xdebug installed (I am using wamp) and I've actually managed to get breakpoints working with sublime text 2 (yea that's right!) so the problem is not with php/xdebug on my pc per se but some setting I am missing.

my php.ini for xdebug:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
;zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
zend_extension ="c:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.4-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0

xdebug.remote_hander =dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_host =127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

Netbeans debugging options are set as defaults except I unchecked "stop at first line" coz I read somewhere to do so.

If you need more info on something let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue for myself (since everything else seems to be in order on my side), netbeans will not debug non root urls for some reason, and of course I dont want to open the root every time so I've made a virtual host for that specific project with a regular url (www.someurl.com) and it seems to be working fine now.

Also I am not sure every single line is needed from my php.ini xdebug settings but I've kept it so, since I am not bothered to check for redundant lines, so if you are not sure about your xdebug settings just copy the whole thing from my Q.